# Predicting CI for a predicted value from a logistic regression model

Tags: r

So I have a specific predicted value that I calculated using logistic regression and now I need to find the CI for that probability. Here is my code:

```
cheese_out <- glm(taste~acetic+person,data=cheese,family = "binomial")
probabilities <- predict(cheese_out,newdata=cheese, type="response")
testdat <- data.frame(acetic = 6, person = "Child")
pred_accp <- predict(cheese_out, newdata=testdat, type="response")
```

and I get my pred_accp value which is 0.1206 but how do I calculate a confidence interval based off of that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use option `se.fit=TRUE` of the `predict` function. This gives you standard errors from which you can calculate the confidence interval. *Example:*

```
out <- glm(I(Sepal.Length > 5.8) ~ Sepal.Width + Species, iris, family=binomial())
testdat <- data.frame(Sepal.Width=3, Species="versicolor")
pred_accp <- predict(out, newdata=testdat, type="response", se.fit=TRUE)

alpha <- .05  ## confidence level
cc <- -qt(alpha/2, df=Inf)*pred_accp$se.fit

setNames(
  pred_accp$fit + cc * c(-1, 0, 1), 
  c("lower", "estimate", "upper"))
#     lower  estimate     upper 
# 0.5505699 0.7072896 0.8640093
```

**Note,** that here is assumed, that data is z-distributed, i.e. `df=Inf`. For t-distribution you may want to specify correct degrees of freedom here.